# I want show text in textbox continually

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

```
for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
{
txtblck =txtblk+ a.ToString();
}
```

In this, txtbox show all the text at the last.
I want to show the text one by one.

Comment: your eyes are too slow...

Comment: @abhi294074 If any of the answers solves your problem please mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        txtblck.Text = txtblck.Text + a.ToString();
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `for` loop is running so fast that you cannot actually see the text of your `TextBox` changing. Use the [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method to pause the loop for a while so you can watch the text changing:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    txtblck =txtblk + a.ToString();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: The Thread sleep doesn't do any good. The UI thread is not updating before the for ends...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (I assumed you were using WPF but any timer will do)

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer;
int a, count;

void start() {
    timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    a = 0;
    count = 10;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    updateString();
}

void updateString() {
    if (a < count) {
        txtblck.Text += a.toString();
        a++;
    }
    else {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```